# High RAM memory usage

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm currently testing a new MySQL server, but I'm new in this so I'm not sure about my parameters, because the RAM is always above 90% of usage.

The server will be setup for a CRM environment of 100 people.

Server specs:

- MySQL version 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4-log
- 16GB of RAM

Changes to mysqld.conf:

```
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size   = 8

# My changes

innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 12
innodb_buffer_pool_size     = 12G
innodb_flush_method         = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size        = 1G
innodb_page_cleaners        = 4
innodb_purge_threads        = 4
max_connections             = 151
open_files_limit            = 112274
table_open_cache            = 56137

log_output                  = FILE
default-storage-engine      = INNODB
character-set-server        = utf8
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    = 300
read_buffer_size            = 64K


# Recommendations [mysqltuner]

long_query_time         = 10
query_cache_size        = 0
query_cache_type        = 0
query_cache_limit       = 2M
join_buffer_size        = 512K
table_definition_cache  = 28468
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

What mysqltuner says in InnoDB Metrics:

```
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 12.0G/22.2G
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (66.6666666666667 %): 4.0G * 2/12.0G should be equal to 25%
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 96 for 8 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.99% (5004553901 hits/ 5004951598 total)
[OK] InnoDB Write log efficiency: 96.96% (8250637 hits/ 8509152 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 258515 writes)
```

Can you help me with this? Should I change anything else in the conf file? Should I upgrade the hardware?

**EDIT:**

GLOBAL STATUS: https://pastebin.com/1kbHTGkL

GLOBAL VARIABLES: https://pastebin.com/KUrBh9wr

FULL PROCESSLIST: https://pastebin.com/39GZdeWB

MySQLTuner report: https://pastebin.com/Khdgf7GP

**EDIT 2:**

I'm using SSD Storage

ulimit: https://pastebin.com/aUAtjnUN

iostat: https://pastebin.com/kjr9GaLB

Comment: Would you rather memory be wasted? Is there anything else apart from MySQL running on that server?

Comment: Nope to both. The server is dedicated for the DB.

Comment: Then what's wrong with MySQL using 90% of memory that's dedicated for the database?

Comment: I was just wondering if that's normal for that environment, of a maximum of 100 users.

Comment: Please post your complete MySQLTuner report AFTER 24 hours of uptime (or a complete workday).  There is much more available information that is useful in managing your dedicated instance recommendations/suggestions.

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server?
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;   after 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report after 1 working day of uptime 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've updated the question with some of that information

Comment: Mr. Martin, Analysis in process.  Thanks for your posted data.  Do you have HDD, SSD or NVME for data storage?  Please post TEXT results of ulimit -a from your OS. Results of iostat -xm 5 3 will reveal your number of cores/cpus, please post.

Comment: @WilsonHauck added new information.

Comment: Thank you for the additional data.  Disclaimer; I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile with downloadable FREE Utility Scripts, tips, and contact information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you want to utilize as much RAM as possible (leaving enough for the O/S, etc), since that means data is *in-memory* instead of being *on disk*.

For a CRM system serving 100 people, you may find 16GB of RAM dedicated to the server is not enough.  My phone has 8GB of RAM, for instance, *and it's just a phone*.

In-memory access times for data is a couple of orders of magnitude faster than accessing data on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS - Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to use more of your SSD iops capacity
thread_cache_size=100  # from 8 to reduce threads_created count of 12,926 in 2 days
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 35,547
read_buffer_size=128K  # from 64K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 12,296
```

You will find these configuration changes will REDUCE CPU busy significantly.
To calculate effectively busy, % busy/cpu count is about 45% busy with your 2 cpu's.

Other observations,
There are more changes needed, this is the tip of the iceberg, but a good start.
We do not normally see com_admin_changes and com_change_db rates above 80 per second.
We do not normally see com_rollback_to_savepoint averaging 1 every 10 seconds.
Select_scan indicates you are doing 61 table scans per second.  NDX's are needed.

Comment: @jose-m-martin Were the suggestions above of any value to you?  Please comment on either positive or negative results.